# How to install Ubuntu on an HP Mini netbook?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I have a Hp mini netbook that has been wiped clean, there is nothing other than the bios on it, it has no DVD and I don't have an external DVD. I can change the boot order to boot from a usb device.

I have downloaded ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386

I have one of these 
http://www.kikatek.com/P100600/34609-IOMEGA-250gb-Select-Portable-HDD-2-5-USB?source=froogle 
currently formatted to NTFS but I can format to exFAT

I have tried Linuxlive USB creator, all that managed to do was dual boot the desktop pc that I'm working off, and when booting on the wiped clean netbook, just left me with a black screen with a blinking cursor

I have also tried Unetbootin, this managed to change my 'My Computer' icon to Install Ubuntu (C:) and now again, my desktop pc dual boots with the Wubi software, the Unetbootin, wouldn't let me select my external drive to write to

Comment: Are you trying to install Ubuntu on the external hard disk or on the internal hard disk by booting through the external one? My expereience with Unetbootin is quite positive for the creation of a bootable pendrive.

Answer (score 0):

On the HP mini 2133 you have to press F9 on boot to go to the boot device menu. 
[Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) you can find information on how to create bootable USB media and install Ubuntu.
For Ubuntu 12.04 the guide is [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support). I hope it helps. Try it out and feel welcome to ask about any specific issues you might experience.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something to do with the ntfs partition. Create a FAT partition on your portable drive AT THE BEGINNING OF THE DISK and use Rufus to write the iso file again to that new FAT partition. The try it again on the HP.

It would be wise to find out more details about your HP Mini. Is it any UEFI or BIOS laptop? Does it supports GPT partition table or just MBR? Rufus offers multiple options depending on what your hardware is capable of.